# Finding the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(3x)}{\left(x^{2}+16\right)^{2}}$ using contour integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

My attempt:
Let $\Gamma = [-R, R] \cup C_{R}$ where $C_{R}: z = Re^{i\theta}, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. The function $f(z) = \displaystyle{\frac{e^{3iz}}{\left(z^{2}+16\right)^{2}}}$ has one double pole inside $\Gamma$ with residue $\displaystyle{-\frac{13i}{256e^{12}}}$ so that $\displaystyle{ \int_{\Gamma} f = \frac{13\pi}{128e^{12}} }$. By Jordan's Lemma \begin{equation} \lim\limits_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_{R}} f = 0 \end{equation} From this we have \begin{equation}  \frac{13\pi}{128e^{12}} = \text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{3ix}}{\left(x^{2}+16 \right)^{2}} \ dx \end{equation} from which I cannot extract the original integral. I've tried other things and even contours that aren't semicircular. In each attempt i've gathered that that since the integrand is even it is difficult to extract $\sin(3x)$ from the contour integral, whereas if the integral had $\cos(3x)$ in the numerator the answer would follow easily. Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: Is this supposed to work or are you just trying by yourself?

Comment: Its an assignment question that ive already submitted an incomplete answer to. Im just interested in how its meant to be solved